# Try to use SetBool and getting error

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use a simple service to switch a server flag, with this code:

```
// Service bind
ros::ServiceServer switch_srv = n.advertiseService(
        "angle_flag_request", angle.serverRequest
);

// angle.serverRequest definition
void RosAngleFlag::serverRequest(
    std_srvs::SetBool& req,
    std_srvs::SetBool& res)
{
    bool req_type = req.request.data;
    if(req_type)
        ROS_INFO("flag true");
    else
        ROS_INFO("flag false");
    
    res.response.success = true;
    res.response.message = "teste";
}
```

And the return are that message:

```
no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const char [19], void(std_srvs::SetBool&, std_srvs::SetBool&))’
```

I've imported "std_srvs/SetBool.h" in my header file...
Someone can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314690/try-to-use-setbool-and-getting-error./) by [Lucas Amparo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39066/lucas-amparo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Change void to bool on serverRequest solve the problem.
And add the Response and Request definition on the function parameters.

---

Originally posted by [Lucas Amparo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39066/lucas-amparo/) with karma: 16 on 2019-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0